# SEO optimization - front page appears twice?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tree

Web server has initial page in the file, let's say, `somefile.html`. *.htaccess* file has the following instruction:

```
DirectoryIndex somefile.html
```

which makes web server to fetch contents of `somefile.html` when web server's root is requested.

However, some page(s) of the website may refer to `somefile.html`, which contains exactly the same content as server's root. Thus this situation leads to same contents appearing on the web  server twice - when `somefile.html` is requested, and when `/` is requested.

How to best correct situation with least effort while keeping website structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 301 redirect to your htaccess file in your document root (preferably before any rules you may already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]*)somefile\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects any direct request for `/somefile.html` to just `/`. As well as any subdirectories: `/foo/bar/somefile.html` to `/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Thank you. What is about redirecting "/" to "/somefile.html"? What is the difference and impact?

Comment: @Eugeny no difference, just a longer URL

Comment: Excuse me for asking again... technically you say it is longer, but from SEO perspective? Any difference rerouting / to somefile (301) or somefile to / (also 301)?

Comment: @Eugeny I guess only if "somefile" is descriptive of the content that the domain name doesn't provide